# C# List of Generic Abstract Class

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

**Presentation:** Hello, I'm a free-time game developer. I wondered if I should look for help in the [Game Development Stackexchange](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/) or even [Unity Answers](https://answers.unity.com/index.html), but It seems more like a C# problem, rather than engine (Unity) stuff.

*I did look through many other questions here and on those sites and watched some tutorials, but didn't get It yet, that's why I'm here.*

**Summary:** Im making a modular windows system for my game UI, and they should have the current features:

- Should be called and referenced by a singleton manager **UIManager.cs**;
- All windows should have some default methods and some fields;
- The base class that all windows inherits from, needs to be serializable so the Unity engine can show them on a visual interface, making easy setting the fields.
  [Example of Serializable Class as a visual component.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hjkr9.png)
- Finally, It also should be easy to get and use a windows from code, since some methods will immediately call them directly from the code.

**Problem:** I need to hold a reference of the generic abstract script that holds de default fields and methods in a List but It seems I can't find a way to declare said List.

**Code Files:**

*UIManager.cs* (This is a singleton that will manage any and all UI elements) [Error code on Visual Studio Community 2019](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3cImX.png)

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
// Unity namespace.
using UnityEngine;

// Inherits my custom singleton abstract.
public class UIManager : MonoSingleton<UIManager>
{

    // THE PROBLEM! I use Lists here and there, but never tried with generics. 
    public List<MonoWindow<T>> windows;

    public override void Init()
    {
        Debug.Log("Window 0: " + typeof(windows[0].windowType).ToString());
    }
}
```

*MonoWindow.cs* (The generic abstract class that is giving me such a headache, hold the default fields and methods for all windows)

```
using System;
// Unity namespace.
using UnityEngine;

// All the windows inherit this, and I also need to know here which script is inheriting it, so there's the T.
public abstract class MonoWindow<T> : MonoBehaviour where T : MonoWindow<T>
{
    public T windowType; // No value needed, only need to know what type (T) of windowType I'm dealing with.
    public WindowCategory category; // WindowCategory is an enum.
    public bool isFocused;

    private void Awake()
    {
        Init();
    }

    // Optional override.
    public virtual void Init() { }
}
```

*LogWindow.cs* (Example of a window script that inherits the MonoWindow).

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
// Unity namespace.
using UnityEngine;

// It inherits MonoWindow, passing its own type LogWindow as the parameter (Should be the value of T).
public class LogWindow : MonoWindow<LogWindow>
{
    public override void Init()
    {
        // Initialize window stuff.
    }

    // Specific window methods.
}
```

**Considerations:** First, I can't set those fields as properties on a interface since the last is non-serializable. Second, if you guys have a better approach for this, feel free to throw your own opinions on usability, ease-of-use, maintenance, performance, etc. Third, If any more info is required, let me know, I think I covered everything about C# though.

Comment: Please don't edit your question with the solution! Your question is a question, the answers give the answer ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the way you try to print it wouldn't work anyway

```
typeof(windows[0].windowType).ToString())
```

since `typeof` doesn't work with dynamic types but expects a compile time constant type like e.g.

```
typeof(MonoBehaviour) 
typeof(int)
...
```

However, You say yourself

> No value needed, only need to know what type (T) of windowType I'm dealing with.

**You don't even need your class to be generic at all!** (A classical case of an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem))

What you are interested in is only the **Type** of your window so you can simply use [`object.GetType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.object.gettype)

```
public abstract class MonoWindow : MonoBehaviour
{
    // You want the TYPE not a reference!
    // This is a read-only property
    public Type windowType => this.GetType();
    // you could also write it as
    //public Type windowType
    //{
    //    get => this.GetType();
    //}
    // Or also
    //public Type windowType
    //{
    //    get
    //    {
    //        return this.GetType();
    //    }
    //}

    public WindowCategory category;
    public bool isFocused;

    // You should make this virtual as well!
    // If you don't any child might be implementing Awake and hide this one
    // => This Awake would not get called in such a case
    protected virtual void Awake()
    {
        Init();
    }

    // So after the comment on Awake it is questionable if you need this method at all 
    // your inheritors could as well override Awake instead.
    // also why is this public if it is called automatically in Awake anyway?
    public virtual void Init() { }
}
```

If you even need such a `windowType` property again is highly questionable since you also could directly use it on the implementation level:

```
public override void Init()
{
    Debug.Log("Window 0: " + windows[0].GetType().ToString());
}
```

Comment: Hello Hugo, thanks for sharing the info about the virtual on awake, I didn't think about that!
Would `Type windowType => this.GetType();` return the type of the `MonoWindow` or the class that It's inheriting It? I see a lambda expression there but I'm not well versed on that.
Thanks for your time.

Comment: It is a readonly property written as expression body ;) It equals writing `Type windowType { get => this.GetType(); }` or also `Type windowType { get { return this.GetType(); } }`. And yes this would return the actual `Type` of the window, not the `MonoWindow` ;)

Comment: Thank you so much Hugo, this is my first time using stack overflow actively and disregarding the negative votes, you helped me with this problem so quickly!
I already accepted your answer on the green markdown, have a good one!

Comment: I also corrected the code and left the previous one commented for other people to consult.